# Battery overdischarging never recover

Tags: batteries, over-discharge

I really need your help!!

I used S-8261 series for battery protection

the following picture is circuit and spec of the battery protection

[image]

[image]

When the voltage drop down under overdischarging voltage (2.7v), the circuit is cut.

But when try to connect a charger to the circuit, it never recover even if the battery voltage becomes higher than releasing over discharge voltage (3.0V, actually the battery is full charged to 4.2V)

Is there any problem on design?

Comment: Discharging a LiPo (which I'm assuming is what the battery is) below around 3.0V can permanently damage it. It's possible that the battery is dead and the protection circuitry is stopping you from potentially causing a fire.

Comment: You could try bypassing the protection circuitry temporarily and slowly charge the battery until it's above 3.0V (which should cause the protection circuitry let you charge it normally again) but I would probably toss the battery and get a new one.

Comment: "actually the battery is full charged to 4.2V"  - Are you saying the cell is _holding_ 4.2V, but the protection circuit won't reset?

Comment: @Bruce Abbott, Yes, the charging logic has no problem, The battery's voltage was 4.2V when I measure that using multimeter. the output voltage was almost 0V, so I thought that the battery and charging logic has no problem but the protection circuit has.

Comment: https://sendvid.com/smpqk4eo

Comment: This link is what I tested, as you can see, even if the voltage become higher than 3.2V but it never recover. The only way to recover the batt is touching both side of MOSFET IC. But If the voltage drop down again, It repeat the problem

Comment: Did you connect the charger between V- and B+ (or V+ with J2 on)? What voltage does the charger put out when its output is open circuit?

Comment: No matter switch turn on or off, the voltage between V- and V+ is 1.7V under charger connection

Comment: Most protected batteries I've used needs 4.5-5V and very low current to unlock after the protection has been tripped.

Comment: "voltage between V- and V+ is 1.7V under charger connection" - this sound like the charger is not supplying any voltage to 'wake up' the battery. I ask again, what voltage does the _charger_ put out when _**not** connected to the battery_?

Comment: @winny if it's a single lipo cell, that would explode it

Comment: @immibis No, the current is in the uA-range.

Comment: @winny if the voltage of your lipo cell is 5V, that would explode it.

Comment: @immibis This isn’t a debate. The voltage is over the tripped protection circuit in order to reset it. There might be other protection circuitrys out there too these days, but this was the common method for a long time. The battery would never reach 5 V due to losses even if the battery was left in the charger indefinitely.

Comment: @winny The voltage across U1 VDD/VSS? Well that connects to B+ and B-, so that's the battery voltage. How exactly do you get 5V across a lipo battery?

Comment: @immibis I’m talking about then the undervoltage protection has kicked in and opened the battery circuit. You don’t seem to understand. Do some experiments, read some datasheets and take apart some chargers instead of asking questions.

Answer (score 1):

When debugging, compare input output conditions for each chip with specs to determine if chip is in spec or out of spec. (fault)  Do for U2 since it is the source and at fault, then U1.

Document everything and compare to spec.
[image]

[image]

Then learn to **interface with twisted pairs** and not inductive loose wires when there is a pulsed circuit. As inductive impedance, pulse noise, functional errors and measurement errors are great above 10MHz or < 30ns rise time when ωL> DCR of wire. Sometimes CM chokes or shielded pairs are needed.

So keep in mind DMM wires are inductive so twist them when connecting to fast switched pins, such as U2-3(bat)  and even U2-2(Gnd)

Example try a 1:1 scope probe on a square wave with 100 mm gnd wire and see all the ringing.  Best is 10:1 probe with no gnd wire just using probe pin,barrel.

This is due to probe ground inductance and signal capacitance , so it has a resonant frequency with long leads which causes ringing on scope and perhaps false operating in circuit. (unstable)

If using long wires, then consider high impedance inputs may need small RF cap to chip gnd without adding significant feedback delay.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, When I check the circuit, the curcuit seems be fine, the FET is connected to batt - also is connected to D, and the FET is connected to EB - also is connected to C

Comment: Ok my fault, I see battery is on other side.  Since both chips do not share a common ground or supply, can you make a list of voltages wrt V- on U2 (left) like U2-1,2,3,4,5 and indicate min-max if pulse  then same for U1 because charger is hi-side and protection is lo-side.